# Como executar uma função Js ao selecionar um input radio

Tags: javascript

Minha pergunta é simples, como posso executar uma função java Script, assim que um input radio for selecionado ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue uma *alternativa* utilizando apenas **javascript**

```js
var rad = document.form.radios;
var prev = null;
for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
  rad[i].onclick = function() {
    qualquerFuncao(this);
  }
};

function qualquerFuncao(e) {
  console.log(e.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio 1" />
  <input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio 2" />
</form>
```

Segue outra alternativa, relativamente mais simples, utilizando **jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:radio[name="radios"]').change(function() {
    if ($("input[name='radios']:checked")) {
      qualquerFuncao($(this).val());
    } else {
      //...
    }

  });
});

function qualquerFuncao(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
  <input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio 1" />
  <input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio 2" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta chamar a função utilizando o evento `change` para o campo do tipo radio:

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $(':radio').change(function(){
      alert ("Codigo função");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```